# iframe is not working on SSL (https)

Tags: ssl, iframe, https, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-8

I am using an iFrame option on a DotNetNuke website.

We are on Evoq Content Basic Version: 08.00.00 (2174) and 04.05.00 iframe version. (the latest 8.0.0 module is not supporting and can not install it on this DNN version)

Our DNN site worked with iFrame well. Then we installed SSL and enables https. Now the iframe content is not loading for https. But it is loading for http request for the same page. The content is loading from a third party website and it should work without any issue. But the iFrame is not loading for https.

Please, can you advise?

Appreciate your support.

Comment: Is the third party content also being loaded from a URL with a secure protocol (https)?

Comment: The third party content is not supporting https. It is only on http.

Comment: That is your problem then. By default most browsers will block insecure content over a secure connection. Some, like IE, will prompt the user to allow the content. Others will require the user to change their settings.

Comment: Since it is loading from an outside content and loading only through an iFrame, Is it essential to be the outside content also secured content?

Comment: Yes, it is essential. A frequent workaround is to implement a reverse proxy.

Comment: Thank you, Brian. So can we load http content as https content then? Do you know any Proxy server for this?

Comment: Most probably, your answer should be the correct answer, Brian. How can I mark it as a solution? Appreciate your great support. Thank you!